# No CD-ROM error during debian installation with USB stick using debian ISO

Tags: debian-installer

I copied debian official netinst ISO to my USB stick and installed system with it just fine.

I use simple-cdd to create my own custom debian installation DVD, which if I burn it onto a DVD, the installation works fine. However, if I use `dd if=debian.iso of=/dev/sdb oflag=sync` to copy my custom ISO to my USB stick, during the installation, it complains no CD-ROM is found.

I have tried couple of suggestions to switch to a shell during the installation and check the /cdrom directory, I found all the stuff is there! Umounting and remounting it does not help the situation. Debian installer still complains.

I also tried to unplug my USB, wait for 30s and then replug it back in. Does not work either.

I wonder what's the difference between my iso and the debian official iso? And how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you use `isohybrid` to make the iso file a hybrid iso file?

Comment: first time hear about this utility.... will give it a try

Comment: Just tried, no luck.... same error